# remove curves from a shape with all curves drawn with pen tool; quick technique

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pen-tool

Is there a simple method in removing all curves from an irregular shape drawn by the pen tool? I want to make it all angular with sharp corners. Basically blocky.

I want to make sure the basic "shape" stays the same but again all angular and no curves.

Thanks you guys!

Comment: Actually I figured out that I can use "simplify path". There is a problem though with that. It adds an extra point and ruins the shape's symmetry. How do I get around that?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with the help of script...Extend Handles

[Scripts by Hiroyuki Sato](http://shanfan.github.io/Illustrator-Scripts-Archive/)

[image]